# Shiny-App with JQueryLayout and DT-table not working

Tags: r, shiny, dt, jquery-layout, html-templates

I am trying to create an app using **JQuery-layouts** (found [here](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/downloads.cfm)) and the `htmlTemplate` function from shiny.

The only thing that is not functioning for now is displaying a DT-Table on the second Tab in the center pane. The problem also remains when trying to use a normal shiny table (renderTable/tableOutput).

- On the tab "Graph" a plotly barchart and a DT-table appear. (works correctly)
- On the tab "Tabelle" another DT-table should also appear. (**doesnt work**)

This div is there, but no table appears:

```
<div id="histoTable1" style="width:100%; height:auto; " class="datatables html-widget html-widget-output shiny-bound-output"></div>
```

*Do I need to specify some I/O-bindings? Or what am I missing?*

---

The app can be ound [here](https://github.com/trafficonese/jQueryLayout) and run via:

```
library(shiny)
runGitHub(repo = "jQueryLayout", username = "trafficonese")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/htmlTemplate%7Csort:date/shiny-discuss/LUXl6wWENGk/1-HX2CuMBAAJ), I managed to figure it out:

A short javascript snippet was missing in the head, which is listening to the click event and then triggers a "shown".

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", "li.tabCenter a", function() {
        $(this).trigger("shown");
    });
</script>
```

The github-example is working fine now and both tables appear.